# Removing labels from chart.js with a media query (or change option value)

Tags: javascript, django, chart.js

I am using Django and have a bar chart in a view like so:

index.html

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById('pollingBarChart');
        var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
                labels: [{% for c in categories %}"{{ c.name }}",{% endfor %}],
                datasets: [{
                    label: '# of Votes',
                    data: [{% for a in active_votes %}
                            {{ a }},
                            {% endfor %}],
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            beginAtZero: true,
                            fontColor: 'white',
                            callback: function(value) {if (value % 1 === 0)
                                {return value;}}
                        }
                    }],
                    xAxes: [{
                        ticks: {
                            fontColor: 'white',
                            fontSize: 12,

                        }
                    }],
                },
                legend: {
                    labels: {
                        fontColor: 'white'
                    },
                },

            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

I have figured out I can set the **xAxes -> ticks -> fontSize to 0** to achieve what I'm looking for, however I haven't been able to figure out how to change this value to 0 with a media query.

I'm still learning JavaScript so not sure the best way to approach this. One possibility I found was to use `window.matchMedia("(max-width: 756px)")` and add a listener. I wasn't able to get it to work though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media query would be a good idea if it's working, but I don't know that.

I have a solution with `chart.js` but I don't know if that's what you want. Right now I remove the ticks completely (including grid lines) if the chart area is small enough. If you just want to hide the ticks you need to adapt the code a little bit like I do in the lines which I commented.

Complete code: https://jsbin.com/lifubiriye/edit?js,output

Important part:

```
function setChartWidth() {
  chartWidth = document.getElementById("chart").width

  if (chartWidth < 756) {
    myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].display = false
  } else {
    myChart.options.scales.xAxes[0].display = true    
  }  
}
```